# Mongodb conditional aggregational query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this simple usecase, where I want to take sum of counters based on different kpiTypes and stores

I have this collection with records:

SensorData:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "storeCode": "111",
        "kpiType": "trafficIn",
        "trafficIn": {
            countValue: 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "storeCode": "111",
        "kpiType": "trafficOut",
        "trafficOut": {
            countValue: 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "storeCode": "222",
        "kpiType": "trafficIn",
        "trafficIn": {
            countValue: 6
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "storeCode": "222",
        "kpiType": "trafficOut",
        "trafficOut": {
            countValue: 2
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "storeCode": "333",
        "kpiType": "trafficIn",
        "trafficIn": {
            countValue: 3
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "storeCode": "333",
        "kpiType": "trafficOut",
        "trafficOut": {
            countValue: 4
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "7",
        "storeCode": "111",
        "kpiType": "trafficIn",
        "trafficIn": {
            countValue: 2
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "8",
        "storeCode": "222",
        "kpiType": "trafficOut",
        "trafficOut": {
            countValue: 2
        }
    }
]
```

Here is my conditional payload for query:

```
const conditions = [
    {
        "storeCode": "111", 
        "kpiType": "trafficIn"
    },
    {
        "storeCode": "222", 
        "kpiType": "trafficOut"
    }
]
```

Now I am expecting following response:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "storeCode": "111",
            "kpiType": "trafficIn"
        },
        "sum": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "storeCode": "222",
            "kpiType": "trafficOut"
        },
        "sum": 4
    }
]
```

Please ask any question, I will try my best to explain this usecase.

Comment: Is your data correct for the document `_id: 8`? The `kpiType` is "trafficOut" but the parent of `countValue` key was `trafficIn`.

Comment: @YongShun that is a typo sorry let me update

Comment: @YongShun please check the question, i made the correction in Collection records

Answer (score 2):

1. `$match` - You need to construct an object containing the `storeCode` and `kpiType` fields to match the object within the `conditions` array.
2. `$group` - Group by `storeCode` and `kpiType`. For the accumulator, you need to check the value of `kpiType` to get the correct field either `trafficIn.countValue` or `trafficOut.countValue`. This should be fine if you have a static/constant value (trafficIn, trafficOut).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          {
            "storeCode": "$storeCode",
            "kpiType": "$kpiType"
          },
          conditions
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "storeCode": "$storeCode",
        "kpiType": "$kpiType"
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$kpiType",
                "trafficIn"
              ]
            },
            "$trafficIn.countValue",
            "$trafficOut.countValue"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ifZIX1KbsSU)

Comment: Thats great, can I use custom aliases to each condition here aswell? Like e.g i want to name condtion cond1, cond2 …

Comment: And from query response i get sum results against those aliases

Comment: const conditions = [
    {
        alias: “cond1”,"storeCode": "111", 
        "kpiType": "trafficIn"
    },
    {alias: “cond2”,
        "storeCode": "222", 
        "kpiType": "trafficOut"
    }
]

Comment: And in response: [
    {
        "_id": {
            alias: “cond2”
        },
        "sum": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "alias”: “cond2”
        },
        "sum": 4
    }
]

Comment: I don't think that is possible as alias field doesn't exist in your document. If you use these values to do filtering, definitely no document will be returned.

Comment: But you can do the mapping in your backend, replace the `storeCode` and `kpiType` fields into `alias`. The key will be you need to remove the `alias` from the `conditions`, this should be part of filter criteria in MongoDB query.

Comment: Right in the above solution you provided, what if i want to have global condition which implies on everything, e.g where companyId: “abc” and type: “sensor”

Comment: What you're asking for here in the comments is different from your original question. @YongShun has answered that original question so it should be accepted. I'd suggest using the playground link that's provided in it to try and modify it to meet your additional needs and if you still need help then it would be best to open a new question.